# how to get name of anchor within live function

Tags: jquery

Using an older version of jQuery, there is some code I need to modify using the live function.  I need to get the anchor text to evaluate it.

```
  $('a').live("click", function () {    
        var anchorText = ''; //???
        if(anchorText === "test") {
           this.text = 'updated anchor text';
        }
  });
```

Comment: AH, a 10 year old version of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `text()` method as both getter and setter of the text content of the element:

```
$('a').live("click", function () {  
  var $a = $(this);  
  var anchorText = $a.text().trim();
  if(anchorText === "test") {
    $a.text('updated anchor text');
  }
});
```

This can be shortened using an arrow function:

```js
$('a').live("click", function() {
  $(this).text((i, t) => t.trim() === 'test' ? 'updated anchor text' : t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">test</a><br />
<a href="#">Foo</a>
```

You should note that `live()` is a very outdated method and was superseded by `on()` quite some time ago. You should look to upgrade the jQuery version when possible.